# How to pass a pointer to vector of pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11

This is a C++ version of a duplicate question. I know the pointers to vectors a bit much in the following, but I did this in order to duplicate a much larger project. The members of info_a are not properly printing from within print_b and I have been unable to properly pass the vector of pointers.

With what I have tried, the members of info_a are not properly printing from within print_b. The first element is fine, but the next two are not.

The structs and print_b are from a third-party api and I am trying to pass in what they are expecting.

Here's the working code ...

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3ad6af6da9409a5

Does anyone see where I am going wrong?

```
typedef struct {
    uint16_t a1;
    uint8_t a2;
    uint8_t a3;
} info_a;

typedef struct {
    uint16_t id;
    unsigned int arr_sz;
    info_a *arr;
} info_b;

void print_a(const info_a* a)
{
    using namespace std;

    cout <<
        "a->a1 0x" << hex << setfill('0') << setw(4) << a->a1 << std::endl <<  
        "a->a2 0x" << hex << setfill('0') << setw(2) << a->a2 << std::endl <<  
        "a->a3 0x" << hex << setfill('0') << setw(2) << a->a3 << std::endl;    
}

void print_b(const info_b* b)
{ 
    using namespace std;

    cout << "b->id 0x" << hex << setfill('0') << setw(4) << b->id << endl      
        << "b->arr_sz " << hex << setfill('0') << setw(2) << b->arr_sz << endl;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < b->arr_sz; ++i) {                             
        const info_a *elem = &(b->arr[i]);                                     

        print_a(elem);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<info_a>>> sp_info_a =
        std::make_shared<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<info_a>>>();              

    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<info_b>>> sp_info_b =          
        std::make_shared<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<info_b>>>();              

    int offset = 0;

    for (uint16_t i = 1; i <= 1; ++i) {
        for (uint16_t j = 1; j <= 3; ++j) {                                    
            std::shared_ptr<info_a> a_info =                                   
                std::make_shared<info_a>(info_a { j, 0x31, 0x32 } );           

            sp_info_a->push_back(a_info);                                      
        }

        std::shared_ptr<info_b> b_info = std::make_shared<info_b>(             
            info_b {
                static_cast<uint16_t>(i),                                      
                static_cast<unsigned int>(sp_info_a->size()),                  
                (*sp_info_a)[offset].get()                                     
            });

        sp_info_b->push_back(b_info);

        print_b(b_info.get());

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shared pointer to the vector of shared pointers. This can't be possibly right design.

Comment: Why are you typedef'ing structs in C++? (Also, where are your includes?)

Comment: @melpomene - because the structs are from a C api that I can't change. The includes can be seen in the working link.

Comment: @Ender Well, if you're going to `typedef` your structs, you could simplify the `shared_ptr` code by typedef-ing your vector and shared_ptr defintions.

Comment: As far as I can tell you're simply printing random bits of memory. Why do you expect this to work? In particular, `&(b->arr[i])` a.k.a. `b->arr + i` just walks off wherever.

Comment: @melpomene - I was trying to dynamically allocate structs and store them in vectors, then pass in a single info_b struct from the vector and have it print the info_a array it contains.

Comment: Do you mean like this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ecb3ae60307f8c5 ?

Comment: Almost, with the  exception that these are temporary and go out of scope outside the for loop, right? I was trying to make them last the life of the program as they're needed.

Comment: Well, you can always copy them elsewhere (or create them elsewhere in the first place).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because you interpret an array of `std::shared_ptr<info_a>` as an array of `info_a`. This will work:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<info_a>> sp_info_a =
        std::make_shared<std::vector<info_a>>();

    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<info_b>>> sp_info_b =
        std::make_shared<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<info_b>>>();

    int offset = 0;

    for (uint16_t i = 1; i <= 1; ++i) {
        for (uint16_t j = 1; j <= 3; ++j) {
            sp_info_a->push_back(info_a { j, 0x31, 0x32 });
        }

        std::shared_ptr<info_b> b_info = std::make_shared<info_b>(
            info_b {
                static_cast<uint16_t>(i),
                static_cast<unsigned int>(sp_info_a->size()),
                sp_info_a->data() + offset
            });

        sp_info_b->push_back(b_info);

        print_b(b_info.get());

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I have been unable to properly pass the vector of pointers

This is the core of the problem. The C API you're calling does not expect a vector of pointers, it expects a vector of structs.

In particular, this bit ...

```
    unsigned int arr_sz;
    info_a *arr;
```

... expects to find `arr_sz` structs in memory, one after the other, starting from `arr`.

Your code allocates all structs separately, then stores the address of the first one in `arr`. The printing code then walks off the end of `arr[0]`, expecting to find the next struct, but as you've allocated them separately, they're stored who knows where in memory.

In order to fix this, whatever you do, you must create the equivalent of a `std::vector<info_a>` (which you can then wrap an `info_b` around, as a sort of array view). This is what gives you the guarantee that the structs are actually adjacent in memory.